# History.push doesn't work in nested child navbar component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have an app like the following:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
```

Then inside the App component I have the following:

```
<Layout>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/methodmembers/'  component={MethodMembers} />
</Layout>
```

inside the Layout component I have a child NavMenu component:

```
 return (
        <Grid fluid>                     
           <NavMenu/>
        </Grid>
)
```

My problem:
Inside the Layout component, when I do the following with withRouter:

```
const { history } = this.context.router;
      e.preventDefault();
      history.push('/methodmembers/');
```

it works FINE and it redirects me to the desired route. 
However, inside the NavMenu component, the same thing does NOT redirect me to another route, it just updates the url.
I am trying withRouter and it still doesn't work.
 Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Is your `NavMenu` a child to the `BrowserRouter` component as well?

Comment: the whole App.js which contains Layout etc is a child of <ConnectedRouter history={history}>

Comment: If NavMenu is not inside BrowserRouter than it can't receive history props

Comment: we are not using BrowserRouter at all. So how come this.context.router works in Layout but not in NavMenu?

Answer (score -1):

You should pass props to NavMenu like:

```
 return (
    <Grid fluid>                     
       <NavMenu {...this.props}/>
    </Grid>
)
```

or you can try to export both component withRouter:

```
export default withRouter(Layout);

...

export default withRouter(NavMenu);
```

and pushing route with:

```
this.props.history.push('/methodmembers/');
```

Comment: I tried this but it only updates the url just like before

Comment: try to not use context, instead use the this.props.history, i've updated the answer

Comment: This also doesn't redirect me. I don't know why context works in Layout